# how can I make xcode create a sound when the build/run fails or crashes

Tags: xcode

The reason I'm asking this is because sometimes I run the project, and wait for 2-3 minutes, expecting it to run, but then it fails while I've turned away from the screen and waste time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xcode is an awesome tool. It allows you to change the *behavior* of your Xcode.

You could tell it, I want you to make the 'Basso' sound when the **Build** Fails, or make the 'Tink' sound when **Running** starts or make the 'Submarine' sound when the **Testing** Starts/Succeeds/Fails/Generates output...

It's best that you take a look into Xcode >> Preferences >> Behaviors

[image]

**New Xcode behavior:** *When* Build, Fails...Play Sound: Blow

---

[image]

**New Xcode behavior:** *When* Running, Exits Unexpectedly...Play Sound: Bottle

---

You could also customize other things as well. e.g. when the build Fails, then what should Xcode show, should it show the debugger or not? Should it show the toolbar or not. You really just need to play around with it. For more see [here](https://10clouds.com/blog/behaviors-xcode-ios-guide/)